# Mod Operator (%) in C with larger divisor than dividend

Tags: c, modulo

Here's my example code in C:

```
int x, y;
x = 7 % 10;
y = 10 % 7;
printf("%d, %d", x, y);
```

It prints: `7, 3`

I understand `10 % 7 = 3`.

I don't understand `7 % 10 = 7`.

I've tried the same code using float variable and got the same answer.  How does mod work when the divisor is larger than the dividend? I would really like to fundamentally understand how to use this operator.

Comment: Forgive me for asking but have you done ANY research on your own?

Comment: `7 / 10` is `0`.  The remainder is `7`.  So `7 % 10` is `7`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that, for positive integers `a` and `b`, `(a + b) % b` is the same as `a % b`.  In other words, you can keep subtracting `b` until the result is less than `b`, and that's the remainder.

Answer (score 4):

Modulus returns the remainder after division.

7 % 10 = 7 because 7 / 10 < 1, e.g. 10 does not fit even once in seven. So the entire value of 7 becomes the remainder.

Answer (score 3):

`10 % 7 = 3` is so because `10 / 7` is `1`. `1 * 7 + 3 = 10`, hence 3 is the remainder.

`7 % 10 = 7` is so because `7 / 10` is `0`. `0 * 10 + 7 = 7`, hence 7 is the remainder.

Comment: @arosenfeld2003 Note this answer works with negative numbers too. Try a few examples with negative numbers. :)

Answer (score 1):

**C11 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**

**Paragraph 5:**

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the
>   first operand by the second; **the result of the % operator is the
>   remainder.** In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undefined.

**Paragraph 6:**

> When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the
>   algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.105) If the
>   quotient a/b is representable, the expression
>   **(a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a**; otherwise, the behavior of both a/b and a%b is undefined.

So, here 7 divided by 10 is 0 with a remainder of 7.

Comment: @Downvoter what am I miss here??

Comment: I just upvoted all the other answers. Not sure why we all got downvoted.

Comment: probably because that's an obvious triplicate. Basic C questions like this _have_ an answer on stack overflow. People tend to downvote answers to trivial questions. I don't (I prefer downvoting questions with no research), but I can understand.